# Diferencia de días y horas entre dos STRING - C#

Tags: c#, android, string, date, xamarin

Estoy necesitando sacar la diferencia que haya en días, horas, minutos y segundos entre dos `string`.
De preferencia utilizando el formato `("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")` pero cualquier formato que incluya fecha y hora servira. He intentado varios metodos y ninguno me funciona.

He visto multiples ejemplos de diferencia entre dos fechas pero yo necesito hacerlo partiendo de dos string. No importa si se tiene que convertir pero ni en eso he tenido suerte.

Entre prueba y prueba llegue a tener como 5 conversiones y multiples variables de la misma fecha, de `string` a `DateTime`, de `DateTime` a `TimeSpan`, etc; y no logre que me funcionara.

Siempre se me generaba algún error de que "el string no contenía formato de fecha y hora correcto" o alguna pequeña variación de ese error al momento de la conversion.

Siempre sera una fecha como: `24/10/2020 04:35:05 PM` y la `hora actual`.

Adjunto codigo:

```
string HaceXtiempo, TiempoHoy, TiempoFecha;

                TiempoFecha = VarGlobal.NFFechaHora[position].ToString();
                TiempoFecha = TiempoFecha.Replace(" a. m.", " AM").Replace(" p. m.", " PM");

                TiempoFecha = Convert.ToDateTime(TiempoFecha).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
                TiempoHoy = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt").ToString();


                DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(TiempoFecha); //No funciono.
                DateTime b = DateTime.Parse(TiempoHoy); //No funciono.

                var hours = (a - b).TotalHours;



                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-NI");

                //string HaceXtiempo, TiempoHoy, TiempoFecha;
                TiempoFecha = VarGlobal.NFFechaHora[position].ToString();
                TiempoFecha = TiempoFecha.Replace(" a. m.", " AM").Replace(" p. m.", " PM");

                TiempoFecha = Convert.ToDateTime(TiempoFecha).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                TiempoHoy = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToString();

                DateTime timespanHoy = DateTime.Parse(TiempoHoy); //No funciono.
                DateTime timespanFecha = DateTime.Parse(TiempoFecha); //No funciono.    
                
                TimeSpan spanHoy = (timespanHoy.TimeOfDay);
                TimeSpan spanFecha = (timespanFecha.TimeOfDay);

                //TimeSpan spanB = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TiempoHoy, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
                //TimeSpan spanA = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TiempoFecha, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
                //No funciono.
                TimeSpan span = (spanFecha - spanHoy);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema está en que el formato `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt` está mal conceptualmente.
`HH` significa *24-hour clock hour, with a leading* lo cual es incompatible con `tt`.

El formato correcto sería `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`, con las horas en *12-hour clock hour*.

Por último, para convertir el `string` a `DateTime` puedes usar la función estática [`ParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0) de la clase `DateTime`.

```
var str = "24/10/2020 04:35:05 PM";
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

También la función [`TryParseExact`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) si prevés posibles problemas de *parsing*.

```
var str = "24/10/2020 04:35:05 PM";
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
var parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date);
if (parsed)
{
    // Handle date
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono muy bien. Una ultima consulta, como podría convertir una fecha antigua como la del ejemplo a una hora en formato (hh:mm tt)?

Comment: @KennyAli y que pasaría si quisieras saber cuántos años,  meses y días han pasado entre esas fechas, ya que la resta de dos fechas en c# no te da este resultado sino que te lo da como el total de días transcurridos entre esas fechas

Comment: @Japv Puedes tomar la cantidad de días y la divides entre 30 para el mes y entre 365 para el año y luego tomas el numero entero del resultado float que te de en caso de que sea mayor a 1. ---------------------------- var hours = (a - b).TotalHours;
                var days = (a - b).Days;
                var minutes = (a - b).TotalMinutes;
                var years = (days / 365);
                var months = (days / 30);

Comment: No, es más complicado, debes tener en cuenta bisiestos, que no todos los meses tienen la misma cantidad de días, si te interesa el algoritmo te lo puedo dar

Comment: Seria excelente, muchas gracias. @Japv

Comment: @KennyAli Hola no se si será mejor hacer una nueva publicacion preguntando eso, dime tu?

Comment: En un formato `hh:mm tt` sólo puedes considerar diferencias de máximo 24 horas, por razones obvias. En cuanto a la diferencia entre dos `DateTime`, ese mismo *scruct* ya tiene implementado la operación resta (`-`), por lo que siendo `date1` y `date2` dos instancias de tipo `DateTime`, `TimeSpan result = date1 - date2; ` obtienes un [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) como resultado.

Comment: @VRoxa, no es asi cuando restas dos datetime obtienes la diferencia en dias, o sea obtienes 1378 dias, no 4 años y un mes y 15 días por ejemplo

Comment: No he dicho lo contrario, @Japv. Simplemente he reducido la complejidad de la cuestión. `TimeSpan` sólo trabaja con días porque no tiene sentido hablar de diferencias entre fechas más allá de los días. Quiero decir, la diferencia entre dos fechas **es un intervalo de tiempo**, no una fecha. Ese intervalo de tiempo no puede traducirse a años, meses, semanas porque no tienes una referencia de dónde empieza o dónde acaba. Sólo puedes hacer esa traducción si tomas unas asunciones estándar (30 días es un mes; 365 un año, por ejemplo).

Comment: Sin esas asunciones, ¿con qué criterio dices que 365 es un año y 366 también porque el segundo es bisiesto? Para afirmar que el segundo cálculo es bisiesto necesitas **una referencia** que no tienes. Lo mismo que los meses, que 61 días son dos meses (noviembre + diciembre, por ejemplo) pero 59 también son dos días (febrero + marzo). Por eso `TimeSpan` sólo trabaja hasta los días, para evitar la pérdida de precisión.

Comment: @VRoxa, mira lo que puse

Comment: @KennyAli, mira lo que puse

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la diferencia de fechas dadas en años, meses y días ej.(han transcurrido 3 años con 2 meses y 1 día) propongo esto:

```
var tiempoInicial = new DateTime(1989, 2, 25)
var tiempoFinal = DateTime.Now;
var tiempoTranscurrido = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
var diferencia = tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial;

tiempoTranscurrido = tiempoTranscurrido.Add(diferencia);
tiempoTranscurrido = tiempoTranscurrido AddDays(-1);
tiempoTranscurrido = tiempoTranscurrido.AddMonths(-1);
tiempoTranscurrido = tiempoTranscurrido.AddYears(-1);

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Han transcurrido {0} años, {1} meses y {2} días", tiempoTranscurrido.Year, tiempoTranscurrido.Month, tiempoTranscurrido.Day));
```

Primero obtenemos una fecha inicial y fecha final cualquiera, declaramos otra variable que será la que nos permitirá guardar el tiempo transcurrido, se inicializa con todos sus valores a **1**, porque el **DateTime** en **C#** no puede tener valores de inicio como **0**, Hacemos la resta de las dos fechas y añadimos esta diferencia a la **variable tiempoTranscurrido**, obteniendo así una fecha, la cual es precisamente el tiempo transcurrido entre las dos fechas, por último restamos **1** al año, al mes y al día, ya que como se inicializa en **1** se debe hacer esto y por último imprimimos el intervalo.

Comment: @VRoxa prueba esto

Comment: @KennyAli, prueba esto